# EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash while assigning a string to the text of a cell's label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
 self.detailTextLabel.text = self.eventAssociation.associatedEvent.searchScheduleString;
```

Occassionally while scrolling the tableView up and down I get a crash one this line where the message is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address =0xsomething-something)`

After the crash I tried printing `self.eventAssociation.associatedEvent.searchScheduleString` on the debugger console, I get the value of the string.

I bring the sequence again responsible for this crash. I thought probably it is that because my model eventAssociation was assign and was getting released but I was still referring to the old address of a deallocated object, so made the model as retain property.but I am still getting this crash sometimes.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    BOAEventListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(nil == cell )
    {
        cell = [[[BOAEventListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }


    if(nil != self.customTableDataSource)
    {
        if(indexPath.section < self.customTableDataSource.count)
        {
            NSArray *eventArray = [self.customTableDataSource objectForKey:[[self.customTableDataSource allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
            [cell setEventAssociation:[eventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            [cell updateFromModel];

        }

    }


    return cell;
}
```

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method where I setTheEventAssociation model and then call updateFromModel which then updates the labels with the new model values.

this is the code for updateFromModel,

```
-(void)updateFromModel
{
    self.detailTextLabel.text = self.eventAssociation.associatedEvent.searchScheduleString;
    CGSize sizeForSchedule = [self.eventAssociation.associatedEvent.searchScheduleString sizeWithFont: self.detailTextLabel.font];

    CGRect frame = self.detailTextLabel.frame;
    frame.size =  sizeForSchedule;
    frame.origin.x = self.frame.size.width - (sizeForSchedule.width + 20) ;

    self.detailTextLabel.frame = frame;


    // find out where title should end
    CGFloat titleEndX =  self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.x - 20;
    frame = self.eventTitle.frame;
    frame.size.width = titleEndX - frame.origin.x;
    self.eventTitle.frame = frame;
    self.eventTitle.text= self.eventAssociation.associatedEvent.eventName;

    // Adjusting size of cell based on text
    [self setNeedsLayout];

}
```

This first line is where I get the crash. What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

As I know `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means you are trying to use the already released object . So Try to retain the object at where you are getting the crash issue .

Comment: As I said, event Association object is a retain property of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your property as "copy" or when you init your string "searchScheduleString" try self.eventAssociation.associatedEvent.searchScheduleString = [stringValue copy];